# How does the data-toggle attribute work? (What's its API?)

Tags: javascript, css, html, twitter-bootstrap

Bootstrap uses a custom attribute named `data-toggle`. How does this feature behave? Does using it require Bootstrap's JavaScript library? Also, which data-toggle options are available. So far, I count

- collapse
- tab
- modal
- dropdown

What do each of these do?

TLDR; What's the API for bootstrap's custom `data-toggle` attribute?

Comment: Yes it requires the bootstrap.js library to work

Comment: None of the answers fit what I wanted: really, I think what I wanted was [Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/twitter-bootstrap/topic-requests/6208), so I'll go [request a topic](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/twitter-bootstrap/topic-requests/6208).

Comment: Also, this question receives a lot of traffic, but no up-votes. I plan to delete it, but am leaving it here for now, for reference from the Documentation topic request page.

Comment: yes... lots of traffic and a great answer by @rogergarrison which should have been  accepted.  He may not have been able to read your mind, but he did a great job of answer the question as it was posed.

Comment: @ChronoFish Well, what can I say? Apparently, asking questions is much harder than answering them, at least for me! :-)

Comment: But awarding rogergarrison the green checkmark isn't [hard]. ;^) 100% agree with @ChronoFish. If you want docs but there aren't docs, you have to accept either Roger's "docs" given here... or, though it doesn't really help anyone, an answer that says, "There ain't API docs for that" or "42" or something. It doesn't help his answer (or us) to say, "It's an unanswerable question." To the extent that it _is_ answerable, [he's answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629974/#comment49363395_30647718). Close the question by accepting. You can move the check if something better comes along.

Answer (score 96):

I think you are a bit confused on the purpose of custom data attributes. From the [w3 spec](http://www.w3.org/html/wg/drafts/html/master/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes)

> Custom data attributes are intended to store custom data private to the page or application, for which there are no more appropriate attributes or elements.

By itself an attribute of `data-toggle=value` is basically a key-value pair, in which the key is "data-toggle" and the value is "value".

In the context of Bootstrap, the custom data in the attribute is almost useless without the context that their JavaScript library includes for the data. If you look at the non-minified version of [bootstrap.js](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/download/v3.3.4/bootstrap-3.3.4-dist.zip) then you can do a search for "data-toggle" and find how it is being used.

Here is an example of Bootstrap JavaScript code that I copied straight from the file regarding the use of "data-toggle".

- Button Toggle

  ```
  Button.prototype.toggle = function () {
    var changed = true
    var $parent = this.$element.closest('[data-toggle="buttons"]')

    if ($parent.length) {
      var $input = this.$element.find('input')
      if ($input.prop('type') == 'radio') {
        if ($input.prop('checked') && this.$element.hasClass('active')) changed = false
        else $parent.find('.active').removeClass('active')
      }
      if (changed) $input.prop('checked', !this.$element.hasClass('active')).trigger('change')
    } else {
      this.$element.attr('aria-pressed', !this.$element.hasClass('active'))
    }

    if (changed) this.$element.toggleClass('active')
  }
  ```

The context that the code provides shows that Bootstrap is using the `data-toggle` attribute as a custom query selector to process the particular element.

From what I see these are the data-toggle options:

- collapse
- dropdown
- modal
- tab
- pill
- button(s)

You may want to look at the [Bootstrap JavaScript documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) to get more specifics of what each do, but basically the `data-toggle` attribute toggles the element to active or not.

Comment: Yes. That is my question. (You're rephrasing the question, instead of answering it.) What I want most, is a "canonical" place to document this feature of bootstrap.

Comment: How did I not answer it? 1) Yes, It requires JavaScript to use the toggle. 2) the feature is implemented in JavaScript using the attribute as a query selector see the code sample 3) Gave a list of values that the data-toggle can have 4) API documentation is at [Bootstrap JavaScript Documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/). A canonical place would be the JavaScript file itself. can't get more canonical than that.

Comment: FYI: What I wanted is not a good fit for [so]. Instead, I created a documentation request [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/twitter-bootstrap/topic-requests/6208).

Comment: Please keep in mind that "buttons" and "button" attach a different plugin.

Comment: So, what does `$('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()` do when executed in jquery?

Answer (score 7):

The data-* attributes is used to store custom data private to the page or application

So Bootstrap uses these attributes for saving states of objects

[W3School data-* description](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp)

Comment: Yes. I mentioned that in my question.

Comment: I am more interested in the API presented by Bootstrap's use of these. The docs don't state that as such.

Comment: FYI: What I wanted is not a good fit for [so]. Instead, I created a documentation request [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/twitter-bootstrap/topic-requests/6208).

Answer (score 2):

The data-toggle attribute simple tell Bootstrap what exactly to do by giving it the name of the toggle action it is about to perform on a target element. If you specify collapse. It means bootstrap will collapse or uncollapse the element pointed by data-target of the action you clicked

Note: the target element must have the appropriate class for bootstrap to carry out the action

**Source action:** 
**data-toggle** = collapse //type of toggle 
**data-target** = #myDiv

**Target:** 
**class**=collapse //I can collapse
**id**=myDiv

This is same for other type of toggle actions like tab, modal, dropdown