# Why cant I use the Jquery show() function in a Div's onclick function without using data data-toggle="dropdown"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` that acts like a `button`. Clicking on this `div`, another hidden `div` gets displayed. My problem now is it doesn't work as expected. I put the data `data-toggle="dropdown"` attribute in the `div` that acts like a button. Why is this?

This is my code:

```js
function showsleevepanel() {
  $('.option-panel').hide();
  $('#sleeve-options-panel').show();
}
```

```css
#sleeve-options-panel {
  width: 17rem;
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="showsleevepanel()" class="card col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center mx-auto mb-2" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <img class="menuIcon" id="menuIcon_sleeve" src="//cdn1.tailorstore.com/ui/emerald/choices/26/sleeve/3.svg"></img>
  <span>Sleeve</span>
</div>
```

Comment: You want to display the `span` when you click on the image? U say in your question that you want to show the `other hidden div` but I don't see that div in your question.

Answer (score 2):

Change your code to this:

HTML

```
<div class="card col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center mx-auto mb-2" data-toggle="dropdown" id="target">
   <img class="menuIcon" id="menuIcon_sleeve" src="//cdn1.tailorstore.com/ui/emerald/choices/26/sleeve/3.svg"></img>
   <span>Sleeve</span>
</div>

<div id="sleeve-options-panel">
   <span>test</span>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$( "#target" ).click(function() {
  $( "#sleeve-options-panel" ).toggle( function() {

  });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Though the question is not quite clear, may be you can achieve what you are looking for with `toggle()` like the following (without using `data-toggle` attribute):

```js
function showsleevepanel() {
  $('.option-panel').toggle();
  $('#sleeve-options-panel').toggle();
}
```

```css
#sleeve-options-panel {
  width: 17rem;
  display: none
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="showsleevepanel()" class="card col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center mx-auto mb-2" >
  <img class="menuIcon" id="menuIcon_sleeve" src="//cdn1.tailorstore.com/ui/emerald/choices/26/sleeve/3.svg"></img>
  <span>Sleeve</span>
</div>
 
<div class="option-panel">option-panel</div>
<div id="sleeve-options-panel">sleeve-options-panel</div>
```

Comment: my question is, why is it that when ever i remove the data-toggle atttibute, it doesn't work ?

Comment: @appzone_oto, even the code snippet you have provided does not work with `data-toggle`. This might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629974/how-does-the-data-toggle-attribute-work-whats-its-api

Answer (score 2):

You are using id #sleeve-options-panel. but in code there is no such id Exist. please add id. then  your code will work

Answer (score 1):

You neither have an element with the `class="option-panel"` nor an element with the `id="sleeve-options-panel"`

If you add the class and id to elements you javascript is working:

```js
function showsleevepanel() {
  $('.option-panel').hide();
  $('#sleeve-options-panel').show();
}
```

```css
#sleeve-options-panel {
  width: 17rem;
  display: none
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div onclick="showsleevepanel()" class="card col-md-12 d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center mx-auto mb-2" data-toggle="dropdown">
  <img class="menuIcon" id="menuIcon_sleeve" src="//cdn1.tailorstore.com/ui/emerald/choices/26/sleeve/3.svg"></img>
  <span>Sleeve</span>
  <span class="option-panel">option-panel class</span>
  <span id="sleeve-options-panel">sleeve-options-panel id</span>
</div>
```

Comment: My question is, why is it that when ever i remove the data-toggle atttibute, it doesn't work ?

Comment: @appzone_oto, i edited my answer, it is working without data-toggle, too. The problem in your code is, that jquery doesn't find the elements because you didn't put the class and id you looking for to an element