# ASP.NET Core 2.1 Razor Page "Please Wait" Modal and Validation

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1

I'm using ASP.NET Core 2.1 Razor Pages and I can successfully call a modal with the following code on submit:

```
 <input id="Submit2" type="submit" asp-page-handler="CreateNew" value="Create Item" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#waiting" />
```

The issue is that calling a modal in this way ignores the server side validation and it never goes away without manually dismissing the modal. In the background, the server side validation works as designed showing the errors. I'd like a way to have the modal not be called if the server-side validation fails, or a better way to have a "Please Wait" message when submitting a form using the server side validation.

I can validate all of the same items again with jQuery, but that defeats the purpose of "Don't Repeat Yourself" and turns server-side validation into a last resort tool.

Comment: That's an HTML tag, not code. The data-binding tags are used by *Bootstrap* to specify that the `#waiting` item will be toggled, they don't do anything else. They aren't related to validation or whether the form's data is sent to the server or not

Comment: Check [How does the data-toggle attribute work? (What's its API?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30629974/how-does-the-data-toggle-attribute-work-whats-its-api) to see what `data-toggle` is actually about

Comment: Check [Add validation to an ASP.NET Core Razor Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/validation?view=aspnetcore-2.2) to see how to add validation to a page and individual controls

Comment: Thanks for the info on the Bootstrap as this is what confused me. As for the validation I see that it will be a combination of Server and Client side in ASP.NET Core.